# pgsql time diffrence?

Tags: sql, datetime, plpgsql

How to write a query to find the time difference ?

time format is like this
**2009-08-12 02:59:59**

i want to compare
 this time with

**2009-08-12 02:59:10**

how to check these two

i want to return some row having the time difference is 30sec

how to write a SQL statement ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select date_part('second',date1) - date_part('second',date2)
```

In SQL you can do like this which give you output in seconds

Comment: I think it does not work well, as it only works in the same minute.
The sentence will return 0 if you compare 2009-08-12 02:59:59 and 2012-10-08 12:13:59

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE time1_column - time2_column = interval '30s'
```

Sorry this is the best I can do, given your description of the problem...

Comment: I believe you will have to allow for the interval being '-30s' also, in the case where time2_column is greater than time1_column.

Answer (score 0):

if both the times are columns in database table, you can directly use
relational operators (>, < and =)
Ex. if you have a table like
Test
(
id bigint,
starttime timestamp,
endtime timestamp
);

then you can have queries like
select * from test where starttime > end time
etc..

If you want to compare two dates in query, you can first convert text to time and then compare them
you can use: datetime function of pgsql
see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/6.3/static/c10.htm
for more details